# How can I insert arabic word to mysql database using java

Tags: java, mysql

I have a java application, want to insert arabic words to mysql database, my code looks like

```
Connection con = null;
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/";
    String db = "students";
    String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    try {
        Class.forName(driver);
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url+db,"root","");
        Statement st = con.createStatement();
        String name = new String(txtName.getText().getBytes(), "UTF-8");
        int val = st.executeUpdate("insert into student(name, roll) VALUES('"+name+"','"+txtRoll.getText()+"')");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But it only insert '??????'. what can i do now?

Comment: Are you sure that ????? is in the database?  It may be that whatever you're using to view the record can't display Arabic.  Write some Java code to read the record back out and compare it to the original data.

Comment: Also, double-check your table is using the `UTF-8` charset (or any other that can handle arabic characters).

Comment: Also, use a [`PreparedStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) to avoid SQL injection attacks!

Comment: Yeah, it also reads ????? in console.

Comment: Agree with @Romain check that the table in your database is using the correct character encoding.

Comment: I am using `utf8_bin` as collation of table cell, which you mention? but nothing happens.

Comment: Don't check it in the console, use the String equals method and print true or false to the console.

Comment: No they are not equal. `if(rs.getString(1).equalsIgnoreCase("كيف")) {
                    System.out.println("YES");
                }`

Comment: But this `if(rs.getString(1).equalsIgnoreCase("???")) {
                    System.out.println("YES");
                }` print YES

Answer (score 24, accepted):

add this variable after db variable declaration:

```
String unicode= "?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8";
```

and then modify your line:

```
con = DriverManager.getConnection(url+db,"root","");
```

to

```
con = DriverManager.getConnection(url+db+unicode,"root","");
```

Answer (score 1):

i faced the same problem but with Chinese data, and it is not only the UTF8 in the db connection is the solution you should also do this:

Ensure that your MySQL configuration encoding is defined correctly. Add these lines to either my.cnf **"in the case if using linux"** or my.ini **"case you using windows"**

```
[client] 
default-character-set=utf8

[mysql]
default-character-set=utf8

[mysqld]
default-character-set=utf8
character-set-server=utf8
```

Comment: I know this is an old post but still.... I attempted setting in the `my.cfg` as you suggested. There appears to be an issue with the entry `default-character-set=utf8` in the mysqld section. There server would not start.

Comment: So far no. Moreover, the additional double-quote stopped appearing.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create your database as a UTF-8 table otherwise no matter what you add it will never be able to store it...

second you need to encode it before you save it, I like to use unicode... one thing about this is that if you have a column that specifies 32 length, you will have to increase that for unicode as a single character takes up 6 characters,

example

letter h appears as U+0068

Comment: For your kind information, I let you know that, I want any language to insert such english, chineese etc as example. I dont know which language in my text box.

Comment: @Pritom, as long as you're using UTF-8 you'll be fine - there's nothing language-specific in his answer.

Comment: Think that table is already created and need to modified, what can I do now please. I am using utf8_unicode_ci as Collation for each row of table structure, is that ok or not?

Comment: If you need Chinese, `utf8mb4` (and collation `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`) would be better than `utf8`.

Answer (score 0):

@maerics I tried using PreparedStatement instead and SQL Injection attack is still able to be done, I think either am implementing the PreparedStatemnt wrong or your feed is incorrect.