# MySQL Java international character(UTF-8) encoding

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, character-encoding, utf

I am trying to insert some data into mysql DB via Java JDBC that contains some International characters.

```
INSERT INTO my_table (`name`, `lat`, `long`, `label`) VALUES('Ädelfors folkhögskola', '57.43611145019531', '15.19722175598145', 'Ädelfors folkhögskola')
```

This query works perfectly fine if i use it directly from mysqlworkbench, phpmyadmin, etc
but when i try with java JDBC the international characters are completely garbled

```
Ädelfors folkhögskola =>  ?��delfors folkh??gskola
```

the solutions i have tried till now include

```
jdbc:mysql://server/database?characterEncoding=UTF-8

Setting - Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
Both my database and table are encoded as utf8 - default collation
```

this is the dump of `"show variables like '%char%'"`

```
character_set_client - utf8
```

`character_set_connection - utf8`

`character_set_database - utf8`

`character_set_filesystem - binary`

`character_set_results - utf8`

`character_set_server - latin1`

`character_set_system - utf8`

`character_sets_dir - /usr/share/mysql/charsets/`

I have tried using both preparesStatements as well as normal Statement

I know there are many similar questions and i have referred most of them but could find a solution.

Some info about environment...
OS - Mac osx 10.6.8
IDE - netbeans

mysql 5.5.23 running on ubuntu

Comment: check the following post and see the accepted answer. I belive you need to set the connection to use unicode. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8433293/how-can-i-insert-arabic-word-to-mysql-database-using-java

Comment: I have already tried that, i forgot to mention jdbc:mysql://server/database?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8

Comment: @PragatiSureka: How do you getting data ? and if using JSP then what is the encoding

Comment: Please, post the `show create table my_table` result.

Answer (score 0):

If you typed your query in a java source or property file you have use an utf-8 editor.
If you are using eclipse (Preferences>General>Workspaces and set text encoding)