# Insert UTF-8 encoded string into mysql database (5.1)

Tags: java, mysql, encoding, utf-8

I have following problem:
When I try to insert a String like "SPRÜCHEթ.txt", it throws an error like:
java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect string value: '\xEF\xBF\xBDCHE...' for column 'comment' at row 1

I have read that these UTF-8 4 byte String characters are supported with mysql 5.5, but I am not able to update the database (there is no webmin update function?)

how can I achieve inserting those complex characters?

Comment: pls check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8433293/how-can-i-insert-arabic-word-to-mysql-database-using-java

Comment: i have checked it... it is useUnicode=true or useUnicode=yes? I have read different things... so it should work with mysql 5.1?

Comment: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8

Comment: You can always loop through the string, look at each char, and if the code is > 128, change it to the HTML entity `&#code;`