# How can I store Arabic data in mysql database by using java?

Tags: java, mysql, database, arabic

I'm creating a new app that is connected to a local host MYSQL database (for now) and the app users will enter the data in Arabic language. 
The problem is that when I insert the data by using java the field in database show me this "?????????" in the main time when I insert the data directly from phpmyadmin it works.

I found on the internet two steps

1. is to set the Collation to utf8_general_ci and i have already did that
2. there are two sentences that should be written within the java code i don't know what they are and how use them they might be the solution.
   [image]

Comment: Please post the code as text not as an image.

Comment: I won't mark as a duplicate (yet), but [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3275524/java-mysql-utf8-problem) may very well be the solution to your problem.  You need to open a UTF-8 compatible connection to MySQL from your Java application.  Otherwise, some other encoding would be used by default (probably not UTF-8).

Answer (score 1):

I think this question answered here:

[How can I insert arabic word to mysql database using java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8433293/how-can-i-insert-arabic-word-to-mysql-database-using-java)

and you can review below answer for more clarification:

[Save Data in Arabic in MySQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6859018/save-data-in-arabic-in-mysql-database)

Note: both links are for Stackoverflow questions.